# If two functions are equal on a (not open) set, are their derivatives equal on that set?

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives

Suppose I have two functions $f$ and $g$ : $\mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$. Suppose that they are equal on $\mathbb{R}$. Note that $\mathbb{R}$ is not open in $\mathbb{C}$. Now should the derivatives of $f$ and $g$ always be equal on $\mathbb{R}$? We could allow the derivatives at the edges to have a constrained approach (i.e. let the limits that define the derivatives be only taken from approaches within $\mathbb{R}$) and ask the same question.

I would be interested also in answers concerning other general spaces, for example taking the domain to be some other subset of $\mathbb{C}$ or considering functions from $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Are $f$ and $g$ assumed to be holomorphic or what? This sounds like the [identity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem).

Comment: $x$ and $x^{2}$ are equal on $\{0\}$ but their derivatives are not. This should give you enough idea at how horribly things can go wrong.

Comment: Good example. But if we consider the derivatives with a constrained approach, they don't really make sense on a 1 point set. Maybe I would be most interested in sets that had at least an open neighbourhood within them and are path-connected.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by 'constrained approach'. Obviously if you only take limits in the reals and the functions are the same there, then the limits will be the same...

Comment: You are right, I guess that part of it was a silly question. But you can still ask the first question.

Comment: If they are _complex_ differentiable, then yes, see @AymanHourieh's comment. If they are only _real_ differentiable, then no, e.g. $f(x+iy) = y^2$ and $g(x+iy) = y$ as Kavi said.

Comment: If they are complex differentiable on the reals, why would the identity theorem hold? The reals are not an open subset. Do they have to be differentiable on an open subset in order to be differentiable on the reals (some neighbourhood of the reals)?

Comment: I meant complex differentiable on the whole domain, but yes, open neighborhood of the reals is enough. If you have more questions, you should maybe open a new thread and be as specific as possible.